# Object of subordinate clause

Tags: subordinate-clauses

Take the following sentence:

> For all work-shifts of any given day, *except for the last one,* the following constraints are set forth.

Does the subordinate clause *except for the last one* refer to *work-shift* or to *day*?

Comment: It applies to the work-shifts. The phrase is "For all X except the last one", where X is "work-shifts of any given day." So the exception applies to the last work-shift of a given day.

Comment: The prepositional phrase, *except of the last one*, might sound better as *except **for** the last one*, and it probably refers to sifts.

Comment: Grammatically, it's ambiguous. But I think you can conclude that it means *work-shifts* by context.

Comment: I read it to refer to *work-shifts* with the comma preceding *except*, and *day* without that comma.

Comment: I think "except for the last one" is *not* a subordinate clause; it's something like a prepositional phrase.

Comment: I read it as excluding all shifts in the previous day, and it took me about a minute locate the issue and make sense of the comments. The meaning that it excludes the last shift of any day did not even register with me the first time through. But logically, you can't "set forth" constraints on the past, so it has to mean the last shift of any *future* day. A bit more context would probably have made the intent clear. English is often ambiguous as to whether a thing or the thing's possessor is being referred to. "I want whosever pottery that is to be fired."

Answer (score 1):

As indicated by the comments on the OP, it only makes sense if *except for the last one* applies to *work-shifts*, but the sentence is grammatically ambiguous.

If you would like to reduce or eliminate the ambiguity, you can try something like the following.

> For any but the last work-shift of any given day, the following constraints are set forth.

If you're willing to separate the sentence, you can try this.

> For all work-shifts of any given day, the following constraints are set forth.
> …
>  The following exceptions apply for the last work-shift of any given day.
> …

Answer (score 1):

As Paul Rowe's answer indicates, there are a number of ways to produce an unambiguous restatement of the original sentence by rewording it. If you wanted to retain all of the original words and make the meaning unambiguous by altering only punctuation and word order, however, you could express the sentence this way:

> For all work-shifts—except for the last one—of any given day, the following constraints are set forth.

By way of fine-tuning the sentence, you could delete the second *for* (the one between *except* and *last*) without any loss of meaning, and you could change the *of* to *on* if you liked the sound of the resulting prepositional phrase better. I think that "apply" reads better than "are set forth" at the end of the sentence, though this is strictly a matter of personal preference. Introducing these changes yields the following version of the sentence:

> For all work-shifts—except the last one—on any given day, the following constraints apply.